# OpenMP parameter sweep parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am new to OpenMP. I want to solve a stiff ODE system for a range of parameter values using parallel do loops. I use the following code in Fortran given below. However, I do not know whether calling a stiff solver(as a subroutine) inside a parallel do loop is allowed or not? Also, I want to write the time series data into files with filenames such as "r_value_s__value.txt" in the subroutine before the return to the main program. Can anyone help. Below is the code and the error. I used `gfortran` with flags `-fopenmp` to compile.

```
   PROGRAM OPENMP_PARALLEL_STIFF

           USE omp_lib
           IMPLICIT NONE

           INTEGER :: I, J
           INTEGER, PARAMETER :: RTOT=10, STOT=15
           INTEGER :: TID
           INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NUM_THREADS=8
           DOUBLE PRECISION :: T_INITIAL, T_FINAL
           CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(NUM_THREADS)
           CALL CPU_TIME(T_INITIAL)
           PRINT*, "TIME INITIAL ",T_INITIAL
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(I,J,TID)

           DO I=1,RTOT
              DO J=1,STOT
                TID=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
                CALL STIFF_DRIVER(TID,I,J,RTOT,STOT)
              END DO
           END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

          CALL CPU_TIME(T_FINAL)
          PRINT*, "TIME FINAL ",T_FINAL
          PRINT*, "TIME ELAPSED ",(T_FINAL-T_INITIAL)/NUM_THREADS
       END PROGRAM OPENMP_PARALLEL_STIFF

       SUBROUTINE STIFF_DRIVER(TID,II,JJ,RTOT,STOT)

          USE USEFUL_PARAMETERS_N_FUNC

          USE DVODE_F90_M

!     Type declarations:

          IMPLICIT NONE


!     Number of odes for the problem:

          INTEGER :: SERIAL_NUMBER, TID
          INTEGER :: II, JJ, RTOT, STOT, IND
          INTEGER :: J, NTOUT
          INTEGER :: ITASK, ISTATE, ISTATS, I

!     parameters : declaration

          DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: s0=0.450D0, dr=1.0D-4, ds=1.0D-2

          DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(NEQ) :: Y, YOUT
          DOUBLE PRECISION :: ATOL, RTOL, RSTATS, T, TOUT, EPS, TFINAL, DELTAT
          DIMENSION :: RSTATS(22), ISTATS(31)
          DOUBLE PRECISION :: bb, cc, ba, ba1, eta
          CHARACTER(len=45) :: filename

          TYPE (VODE_OPTS) :: OPTIONS

          SERIAL_NUMBER=3011+II+(JJ-1)*RTOT
          IND=TID+3011+II+(JJ-1)*RTOT
          WRITE (*,12)SERIAL_NUMBER,TID
    12    FORMAT ("SL. NO. ",I5," THREAD NO.",I3)

          r=(II-1)*dr
          s=s0+JJ*ds

          EPS = 1.0D-9

!         Open the output file:

          WRITE (filename,93)r,s
    93    FORMAT ("r_",f6.4,"_s_",f4.2,".txt")
          OPEN (UNIT=IND,FILE=filename,STATUS='UNKNOWN',ACTION='WRITE')

!     Parameters for the stiff ODE system

           q0 = 0.60D0;    v = 3.0D0
           Va = 20.0D-4;  Vs = 1.0D-1
           e1 = 1.0D-1;   e2 = 1.10D-5; e3 = 2.3D-3; e4=3.0D-4
          del = 1.7D-4;   mu = 5.9D-4
           al = 1.70D-4;  be = 8.9D-4;  ga = 2.5D-1

!         S and r dependent parameters

           e1s = e1/s;    e2s = e2/(s**2);   e3s = e3/s;    e4s = e4/s
          dels = del*s;    rs = r*s
           e1v = e1/v;     e2v = e2/(v**2);   e3v = e3/v;    e4v = e4/v
          delv = del*v;     rv = r*v

!         SET INITIAL PARAMETERS for INTEGRATION ROUTINES  

          T = 0.0D0
          TFINAL = 200.0D0
          DELTAT = 0.10D0
          NTOUT = INT(TFINAL/DELTAT)
          RTOL = EPS
          ATOL = EPS
          ITASK = 1
          ISTATE = 1

!         Set the initial conditions: USING MODULE USEFUL_PARAMETERS_N_FUNC

          CALL Y_INITIAL(NEQ,Y)

!        Set the VODE_F90 options:

          OPTIONS = SET_OPTS(DENSE_J=.TRUE.,USER_SUPPLIED_JACOBIAN=.FALSE., &
          RELERR=RTOL,ABSERR=ATOL,MXSTEP=100000)

!         Integration:

          DO I=1,NTOUT

          TOUT = (I-1)*DELTAT

          CALL DVODE_F90(F_FUNC,NEQ,Y,T,TOUT,ITASK,ISTATE,OPTIONS)

!         Stop the integration in case of an error

          IF (ISTATE<0) THEN
            WRITE (*,*)"ISTATE ", ISTATE
            STOP
          END IF

!         WRITE DATA TO FILE

          WRITE (IND,*) TOUT,T, Y(NEQ-2)

         END DO


         CLOSE(UNIT=IND)

         RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE STIFF_DRIVER
```

> At line ** of file openmp_parallel_stiff.f90 (unit = 3013)
>   Fortran runtime error: File already opened in another unit

Comment: I suspect that, in `stiff_driver`, for two distinct `II` and `JJ` pairs the values of `r` and `s` are the same (to 4 and 2 decimal places).  Can you check that?

Comment: As your code currently stands, one thread will not do simultaneous calls to `STIFF_DRIVER`, therefore you might use a simpler scheme to derive the unit number, e.g. `3010+tid`. With Fortran 2008 compilers it is also possible to do `OPEN(NEWUNIT=ind, ...) .... CLOSE(UNIT=ind)`. Calling `OPEN(NEWUNIT=ind, ...)` connects the file to an unused unit number and returns the latter in `ind`. If the Fortran runtime is not thread-safe, you should surround the `OPEN` and `CLOSE` statements with critical sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the format that you chose: `f6.4` for `r` will overflow for `r>=10`. Then, the output will be six asterisks `******` (depending on the compiler) for all values of `r>=10` on all threads. The same holds true for `s`.

I would suggest to either limit/check the range of these values or extend the format to honor more digits.

---

As @francescalus mentioned, another possibility is hit a combination of `II` and `JJ` where `r` and `s` are identical.

Just for the fun of it - let's do the math:

```
r=(II-1)*dr
s=s0+JJ*ds
```

From `r=s` follows

```
(II-1)*dr = s0+JJ*ds
```

or

```
II = 1 + s0/dr + JJ*ds/dr
```

Using the constants `s0=0.450D0, dr=1.0D-4, ds=1.0D-2` yields

```
II = 4501 + JJ*10
```

So, whenever this combination is true for two (or more) threads at a time, you run into the observed issue.

Simple solution for this case: add the thread number to the file name.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus and Alexander. FORMAT is the problem as both of you rightly pointed out.